# Web API, where to put private methods?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

So I was wondering the other day, where to put private methods, that do some dirty work in Web API.

I need to extract certain things from JSON, methods will do the job and return some result.

So where do I keep those methods? 
do I need to write a separate library (dll)?
or just do this stuff in the controller?

Comment: You can write your methods in same controller or create other controller, as you need it and it depends on usage of it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t think it can have a single answer – it depends on…

If you think this private method can be reused from some other controller in future, better to have a separate class, if you think it can be reused from separate modules (not just from controllers), a separate class library project can be the answer.

But if you consider this private method is designed to support for a specific action of a controller, you can write within controller, before taking any decision a few more parameters to be considered like unit testability or slimness of API etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your controller thin as much as possible. You can move logic code to service package, for example JSONService class or JSONLib. 
I often use following layout:

```
controller/
lib/
service/
model/
```